# How can you create a user and a company model at the same time? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple register account form on my front page, and I want that when a user is created, a company model is created in the same instence with a user model, but I don't know how to properly define it.

```
public function create(Request $request) {

    $create = User::create([
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);
    if($create){

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
}
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
     'email', 'password', 'paypal_email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
'email_verified_at', 'user_id'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

/**
 * Get user company
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */

public function company ()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
}
```

Company model:

```
class Company extends Authenticatable
{
 use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'company_name', 'phone', 'gst_hst_number', 'country'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [

];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

create_companies_table values are all nullable, the logic is, that you can update all info later, but when you create a user, a company model is created also, the data in the tables you can fill later.

How can I properly define the create function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the `User` is created successfully.

```
if ($create) {
    // This will create your company by passing empty attribute to it, since all of the fields in the model are nullable.
    Company::create(['user_id' => $create->id]);
}
```

If I was you I would do this in the model. I would make a method that will do that for me. Lets say that I will create a `createWithCompany` method in the `User` model and do something like this:

```
public static function createWithCompany($attributes)
{

// Begin a transaction since we are creating a company and then the user.
    DB::beginTransaction();

    Try {
// We create the company
        $comapny = Copmany::create([]);

// Creates the user with the needed data.
        $user = self::create(array_merge($attributes, ['company_id' => $company->id]));
// We commit everything if we have no errors during the insert
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
// We rollback the company and the user if one of them fails to be created.
        DB::rollBack();
    }


    return $user;
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that if later on you want to create from the `console` with a `command` some kind of script that inserts `Users` and creates `companies` for them you can do this with a single method and the code with be consistent with your controller.

**I'm assuming that 1 company can have many users.**